# Configuring @RepositoryRestResource path with multi-segment for nested relationships

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I've created 2 HATEOS @RepositoryRestResource for a Customer that has many Address :

```
class Customer {
  ...
  Long id;
  @OneToMany(
  Set<Address> addresses;
  ...
}

class Address {
  ...
  Long id;
  ...
}

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "customers")
public interface CustomerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Customer, Long> {
}

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "addresses")
public interface AddressRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Address, Long> {
}
```

I am able to get an Address entity with the following multi-segment path

```
Get Address 1 of Customer 1: GET /customers/1/adresses/1
```

BUT ... I'm not able to PATCH, PUT or DELETE an address using the same multi-segment path

```
Update Address 1 of Customer 1: PATCH, PUT or DELETE /customers/1/adresses/1
```

I always get a 404 - Not Found. It only works if I use the address endpoint

```
Update Address 1 : PATCH, PUT or DELETE /adresses/1
```

**Is there a way to configure the @RepositoryRestResource so that I can update/delete an address (or any entities related to customer via the customer endpoint (/customers/{customerId}/addresses/{addressId}) ?**

Regards

The code is available at https://github.com/fdlessard/spring-boot-repository-rest-resource

Answer (score 0):

When you GET `/customers/1/addresses/1`, the response JSON should be

```json
{
  "country": "XYZ",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8888/addresses/1" <-- here
    },
    "address": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8888/addresses/1"
    }
  }
}
```

Use the link `self`, that is, `http://localhost:8888/addresses/1` for update.

Actually, when you GET `/customers/1/addresses`, the array `addresses` in response JSON already gives you the true URI `/addresses/1`.

```json
{
  "_embedded": {
    "addresses": [
      {
        "country": "XYZ",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8888/addresses/1"  <-- here
          },
          "address": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8888/addresses/1"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8888/customers/1/addresses"
    }
  }
}
```

Remember, when play with HATEOAS, discover link and follow the href, rather than hardcode the URI. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#client.link-discoverer